# Flutter class definition with 'Object' class member

Tags: flutter, class, object

in my Flutter project, I want to decide class member type during execution. For this, I wrote the following code with the help of this entry: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17766 But I cannot access function printt(). It gives error: The method 'printt' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

```
void main() {
  Merchant merchant = Merchant('A');
  merchant.mp!.printt();  // this line gives error: The method 'printt' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
}

class Merchant {
  Object? mp;

  Merchant(String mpStr) {
    if (mpStr == 'A') mp = createInstanceOf<A>();
    if (mpStr == 'B') mp = createInstanceOf<B>();
  }

  T? createInstanceOf<T>() {
    final factories = <Type, T Function()>{
      A: () => A() as T,
      B: () => B() as T,
    };

    final createInstance = factories[T];

    return createInstance?.call(); // Same as createInstance() but null safety
  }
}

class A {
  void printt() {
    print('I am function of class A');
  }
}

class B {
  void printt() {
    print('I am function of class B');
  }
}
```

Comment: If `mp` is only `class A` or `class B` the best is to create a mother class with an empty `void printt()` method and so `class A` and `class B` could extends of this mother class to implement their own `void printt()` method. So in `class Merchant` replace `Object?` by the mother class of `class A` and `class B`

Answer (score 0):

Like @Yannis mentioned, create an abstract class, let's say `PrintT`, with all common methods of A and B and set `mp` as this type. Then, set both class A and B to implement it. The code is going to be the following:

Check out the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0aa83e0e548c68d8d071197ddfdcd7b7).

```dart
void main() {
  Merchant merchant = Merchant('A');
  merchant.mp!.printt();
}

class Merchant {
  PrintT? mp;

  Merchant(String mpStr) {
    if (mpStr == 'A') mp = createInstanceOf<A>();
    if (mpStr == 'B') mp = createInstanceOf<B>();
  }

  T? createInstanceOf<T>() {
    final factories = <Type, T Function()>{
      A: () => A() as T,
      B: () => B() as T,
    };

    final createInstance = factories[T];

    return createInstance?.call(); // Same as createInstance() but null safety
  }
}

abstract class PrintT {
  void printt();
}

class A implements PrintT {
  void printt() {
    print('I am function of class A');
  }
}

class B implements PrintT {
  void printt() {
    print('I am function of class B');
  }
}
```